# Optimally calculating multiple database items into a configuration

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, algorithm, math

Good morning!  I'm working on a couple of optimization things here...I can't find the "best" answer to this, so I thought I'd ask you geniuses.  Thanks in advance for your thoughts!  Always appreciate this community :)

- We have a database, it has about 150 items in it, maybe more (haven’t finished it) of various widgets (long story, leaving it out for the sake of simplicity).  These items have 3 values:  we’ll just call it VALUE A, VALUE B, and VALUE C.  So an example of this view in the db could be this (and this is mysql by the way, but for the sake of structurally showing it, we’ll go with JSON for now):
- {“ItemID” : 1, "A" :50, “B”: 20 , “C”: 4}
- {“ItemID”: 2 , ”A” :10, “B”: 40 , “C”: 10}
- {“ItemID”: 3 , ”A” :16, “B”: 9 , “C”: 30}
- {“ItemID”: 4 , ”A” :4, “B”: 3 , “C”: 14}
- And so on…150+ times.
- Then we have a user, who has a specific number for item A, B and C that they need to meet with a combination of the items.  For example, lets say the users number is A: 26  B: 49  C: 40.  We would want to find a combination of items in the database to give them to meet that number.  In the above item list example, items 2 and 3 can meet this exactly.
- Additionally, we can use semi-proportions of the items with multipliers in quarters and halves.  So for example, the user total may be 55, 40, and 9.  You could use Item1, and also half of Item2 to accomplish this.

That’s essentially all we’re trying to do here.  I think there are probably a lot of ways to accomplish this, but making sure the code efficiency is premium is important, so rather than just stumbling down the path with whatever way works first, I wanted some outside expertise/thought process to see how you’d go about this.

Again, greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: the only way to do this with javascript is to select every item from the table and run the algorithm in js, which is definitely not going to be the fastest way, that said, why is javascript tagged? if you want speed/efficiency you want to do it myth mysql, right?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. correct, Javascript is just tagged because I'm using JS on the frontend and wanted to give folks the option, mysql would be preferrable.

Comment: What language are you using to interface with MySQL? A server side language might be faster than JS, especially if you have to move all the data over the wire in order to operate on it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. node.js :)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, but I think this problem might not be able to be solved efficiently. Your problem is very related to the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Specifically, you might want to look into the multi-dimensional knapsack problem.

Since your input consists of whole numbers only, you might be able to find a pseudo-polynomial solution to it, but I doubt it.

You only have 150 (x4 if you allow halfes and quaters) elements. Depending on the size of the queries you might be able to solve the problem brute-force in a reasonable time-span.

Comment: @sailbot lets say for the sake of the argument that there IS a correct answer for every total.  As in we only limit it to values that can be completed.  A bunch of online systems do similar functions, for example...a really similar one is a nutritional calculator.   example > https://www.eatthismuch.com/   You define how many carbs fats and proteins you want to eat each day and it finds foods that will meet the criteria.  Still dont know the best way they do this :), but its an example of what I'm trying to get towards.

Comment: additionally @sailbot, thanks for the reference to Knapsack Problem!  That opened up some doors for me :)